# Not applicable for the main.dart configuration

Tags: flutter

I am facing the following issue while selecting the device for emulator. It shows "nothing here" in devices marked with green and "not applicable for main.dart" for the one marked with red.
Image- [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DezpU.png)

I came across a warning regarding white spaces in android sdk path when i went to tools>sdk manager>android sdk
Hence i shifted the entire android folder to C:\Android\sdk and i got rid of that warning but now on running the command 'flutter doctor', my android sdk cannot be located. This could be because i changed the path of sdk but i also changed the environment variable.

Images as follows-
flutter doctor-[flutter doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdBiw.png)

Path environment variable in SYSTEM variable-[environment variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxVJ5.png)
SDK manager-[android sdk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7pq4.png)

What else am i missing here?

Answer (score 5):

You might have missed setting the Project SDK.

Go to File > Project Structure

Under Project Settings > Project, make sure you've selected the latest Project SDK, Apply Changes and restart Android Studio, then you will be able to see and open from the list of installed emulators.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I actually had to reinstall Android Studio with the same path(which had white spaces) but found out that my virtualization technology wasn't enabled last time. I enabled it and now list of my installed emulators is seen and it worked. Probably that white space in the path warning didn't cause the list of devices not available.